# Verb im Singular oder Plural in Verbindung mit "Eine Reihe/Menge/... von ..."

Tags: verb, grammatical-number

Welcher der beiden Sätze ist korrekt:

> Eine Reihe von Aufgaben, die erledigt werden *muss*.

und / oder

> Eine Reihe von Aufgaben, die erledigt werden *müssen*.

Erster Satz klingt korrekt, wenn man die wörtliche "Reihe" als Subjekt nimmt. Man könnte sich allerdings darüber streiten, ob sich nicht eher nur auf die "Aufgaben" bezogen wird.

Zweiter Satz klingt korrekt, wenn man "Eine Reihe von" mit beispielsweise "Viele" ersetzt.

Andersherum klingen die Sätze:

> Es *muss* eine Reihe von Aufgaben erledigt werden.

und

> Es *müssen* eine Reihe von Aufgaben erledigt werden.

Mein Sprachgefühl neigt stark zu einer der Optionen, allerdings stieß ich im Dialog mit anderen Personen auf entgegengesetzte Meinungen.

Comment: Beispiele aus http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/de/res?word=eine+Reihe+von: "Nun _äußerte_ eine Reihe von Gesellschaftern [...]", "Auf die Bundesanwaltschaft _wird_ wohl eine Reihe von Schlappen zukommen, [...]". Eine grammatikalische Begründung oder ein Verweis, der diese Beispiele bestätigt, wäre allerdings hilfreich.

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach bezieht sich im ersten Beispiel "die" auf die Aufgaben: "Aufgaben, die erledigt werden müssen". Also zweiter Satz korrekt. Im zweiten Beispiel ist es "eine Reihe (von Aufgaben)", also muss, also erster Satz korrekt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die deutsche Sprache erfordert **KNG-Kongruenz**, also die Übereinstimmung von Kasus, Genus und Numerus zwischen Subjekt und Prädikat. Besteht das Subjekt aus mehreren Teilen, die an sich schon nicht im Numerus übereinstimmen, wird die Sache kompliziert:

Beide Sätze sind korrekt, geben u.U aber einen leicht unterschiedlichen Sachverhalt wieder, je nachdem, ob man sich auf die *Gruppe*, oder die *Einzelteile* bezieht. Der Unterschied ist allerdings marginal. Im Allgemeinen sollte man aber das Verb im Singular nehmen.

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/newsletter/Duden-Newsletter-180512) sagt dazu (Das konkrete Beispiel bezieht sich auf Nominalausdrücke, ich denke aber, man darf die Aussage auf dein Beispiel übertragen):

> Folgt einem Wort wie „Reihe, Menge, Gruppe“ ein Nominalausdruck im Plural, dann stehen Verb und Prädikativ in Übereinstimmung mit dem Kern des Subjekts in der Regel im Singular. Der Plural gilt aber auch als korrekt: „Eine Reihe von Zinnsoldaten war/waren die martialischen Wächter dieses Tores.“

[Hier](http://www.univie.ac.at/Germanistik/schrodt/grammatik/uebersicht_zweifelsfaelle.htm) wird eine ähnliche Aussage gemacht:

> 1) Subjekt im Singular
>
> a) Wenn das Subjekt im Singular steht und dennoch eine Mehrzahl bezeichnet, oder das Subjekt aus mehreren Teilen besteht, kann es zu Konflikten bezüglich der Kongruenz im Numerus kommen.
>
> *Eine Reihe von Leuten hat (auch: haben) sich beschwert.*
>
> *Ein Kilogramm Erbsen wurde (auch: wurden) gekocht.*
>
> *Das Gelächter, die Heiterkeit klangen (auch: klang) aufgesetzt.*
>
> Die finite Verbform kann in diesen Fällen sowohl im Singular als auch im Plural stehen. Eine feste Regel gibt es nicht.

Es gibt (konstruierte) Satzbeispiele, die eher den Plural erforden:

> Über den Tag hinweg schlugen eine Reihe von Bomben ein, von denen einige trafen, andere nicht.

Hier funktioniert der Singular meiner Meinung nach nicht mehr, weil die Verbform nicht mehr zum Relativsatz passen würde.

Comment: In den ersten beiden Beispielsätzen der Frage gibt es gar kein Subjekt, da das kein vollständiger Satz ist. Wäre es ein Satz, etwa: "Hier ist eine Reihe von Aufgaben, die erledigt werden muss/müssen", wäre das Subjekt eindeutig im Singular, nämlich die komplexe Nominalphrase [eine Reihe von Aufgaben]. Deine ersten Sätze sin  also ein bisschen irreführend. Der springende Punkt ist vielmehr, worauf sich der Relativsatz bezieht.

Comment: Bei den Zinnsoldaten muss aber, beim Singular, "der martialische Wächter" fortgesetzt werden, oder?

Comment: @userunknown Das denke ich auch - Das Zitat ist aber exakt so wiedergegeben, wie ich es gefunden habe - Ich wollte das nicht ändern, auch weil dieser Teil des Beispielsatzes für die aktuelle Frage an sich irrelevant ist. Es geht hier um die Kongruenz zwischen *Reihe* und/oder *Zinnsoldaten* und dem Prädikat

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Nein. *Hier **sind** eine Reihe von Aufgaben, die erledigt werden  müssen* ist genauso richtig.

Comment: @tofro: "Hier sind eine Reihe von Aufgaben, die erledigt werden müssen" wäre zumindest eine Verletzung der Numerus-Kongruenz. Denn das Subjekt ist im Singular: "Eine Reihe (von Aufgaben)". Aber der Duden gibt Dir Recht. Ein interessanter Ausnahmefall der KNG-Kongruenz! Danke für den Hinweis!

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach *eine Reihe von...* kann als *Container* betrachtet ein Subjekt sein oder eine einfache Mengenangabe - dann bestimmen die *Aufgaben* den Numerus. Ich sehe das nicht als Verletzung der Kongruenz.

Comment: Naja, ich denke, semantisch ist das natürlich ein Pluralobjekt. Aber syntaktisch ist es eine Nominalphrase im Singular. Nimm als Variante den Satz *"Eine Familie von Verbrechern gehen einkaufen." Der ist grammatisch völlig analog, aber wird wohl als falsch eingestuft.  Ich denke daher schon, dass die Behandlung von "eine Reihe von" als Plural eine habitualisierte Ausnahme von der Numerus-Kongruenz ist.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Das liegt daran, dass **Familie** nicht als Mengenangabe funktioniert. *Eine Million Menschen leidet/leiden unter Haarausfall* wäre ain Analogon.

Comment: @tofro Stimmt, das ist der Unterschied. Du hast mich überzeugt. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Beide Sätze sind korrekt. Im ersten Fall bezieht sich der Relativsatz auf die "Reihe", im zweiten Fall auf die "Aufgaben". Die Klammern zur Veranschaulichung der grammatischen Struktur:

> [Eine Reihe von Aufgaben], die erledigt werden muss.
>
> Eine Reihe von [Aufgaben, die erledigt werden müssen.]

*Semantisch*, also auf der Ebene der Bedeutung, gibt es hier keinen Unterschied, beide Phrasen sagen das gleiche aus. Daher kommt wohl auch die Uneinigkeit.

Bei den anderen beiden Sätzen ist es anders. Hier ist nur

> Es muss [eine Reihe von Aufgaben] erledigt werden.

korrekt, weil das Prädikat sich hier aufgrund der Wortstellung auf die Phrase  [eine Reihe von Aufgaben] bezieht, die das Subjekt des Satzes und eine Nominalphrase im Singular ist.

Comment: Die oberen zwei Beispiele könnten fortgesetzt werden "bereitet mir Kopfzerbrechen", nicht aber mit "bereiten mir Kopfzerbrechen".

Comment: @userunknown Ich denke es macht Sinn, in der Fortführung denselben Numerus beizubehalten. Mit welcher Begründung bildet die Erweiterung des Satzes hier eine Ausnahme, sodass nur der Singular funktionieren würde?

Comment: @PabloSichert: Die Klammerung: "(Eine Reihe von (Aufgaben, die erledigt werden müssen)), bereitet mir Kopfzerbrechen." Alternativ: "Eine Reihe von Aufgaben, die erledigt werden müssen und mir Kopfzerbrechen bereiten."